# Where in terms of priority are eventlisteners in the event callback?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-loop

So in this [post](https://javascript.info/event-loop) , the macrotask queue seems to include movemouse. But then with this code

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="but_one" onclick='button_one()'>Button 1</button>
    <button id="but_two" onclick='button_two()'>Button 2</button>
</body>
<script>
    //document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => console.log("mouse move"));

    function button_one() {
        console.log("button one")
    }

    function button_two() {
        console.log("button two before")
        setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout : before sleep"), 0)
        autoResolve().then(msg => console.log(".then before sleep " + msg));
        sleep(5000);
        autoResolve().then(msg => {
            sleep(2000);
            console.log(".then after sleep " + msg)
        });
        setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout : after sleep"), 0)
        console.log("button two after")
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        const date = Date.now();
        let currentDate = null;
        do {
            currentDate = Date.now();
        } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
    }

    async function autoResolve() { return "resolved" }
</script>
</html>
```

If you click button 2 and then 1, you can see that both promises (microtasks) are executed before button 1 click is registered, which makes sense to me. However both timeouts (macrotasks) seem to occur after, even the one that was queued before I clicked. This to me suggests that the listener has it's own 3rd queue but no source says this.

The same is observed with logging mousemove, however I removed that for the purposes of the console in the code-snippet.

Why does this happen?

edit: So this was done in Chrome Version 83.0.4103.61 on Windows 10 PC

Comment: Very interesting experiment.

Comment: The problem with that experiment is that it relies on so  much things left to implementations... For instance, Chrome will not only treat all timeouts as lower priority, but they will even add a minimum 2ms timeout, so your code is not really queuing a task. Using postMessage would, but then comes the fact that specs now *recommend* taht mouse events are throttled by UA to screen refresh rate, which means UAs may try to force it to fire in the next rendering frame, which wouldn't be a simple prioritization matter.

Comment: @Kaiido It doesn't *rely* on the implementation-specific things, it serves to expose them.

Comment: @Bergi my point is that there are so many in this little snippet that it can't expose any one in particular. For instance even with the incoming [Prioritized postTask API](https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/blob/master/PrioritizedPostTask.md) on (chrome:flags#enable-experimental-web-platform-features) and using `postTask(cb, 'user-blocking')`, [mousevents still win](https://jsfiddle.net/15haozy3/), while our `postTask` should have the highest priority. That shows it's not a simple matter of prioritizations, and that one can't tell exactly what happens.

Comment: @Kaiido Agreed, but I don't think the question wanted to expose a specific thing - it asks the generic "*Why can't we tell?*".

Comment: @Bergi it asks "Why does this happen?". And while both yours and TJ's answers point to (the same) valid point that browsers have prioritization models, this exact example is unfortunately too complex to be sure said prioritization is the real point here. I would personally suspect some kind of mess with the mouse event's throttling to rendering frame here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification says that the event loop may have multiple task queues. Here's step 1 of the [processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model):

> 1. Let *taskQueue* be **one of the event loop's task queues, chosen in an implementation-defined manner**, with the constraint that the chosen task queue must contain at least one runnable task. If there is no such task queue, then jump to the microtasks step below.

*(my emphasis)*

It's not surprising that a browser might (conceptually) have events and timers in separate task queues in order to prioritize an event over a timer callback, perhaps especially when that event has been delayed because the JavaScript thread was too busy to handle it earlier.

I don't think it's specified any more ...er... specifically than that that "implementation-defined manner." I get the behavior you describe (the "button one" event before the timer callback) with Chrome, and I get the timer callbacks before the event with Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

The macrotasks to run come from multiple so-called task sources. The browser is free to decide in what order to serve them, using multiple queues, as long as the events of each source occur in sequence. Event listeners and timeouts are different sources, and apparently your browser deems the click event more important.

Comment: "one for each so-called task source" not necessarily no. Per specs, an event loop could have a single task queue, and in the facts, some UAs even have multiple task queues for the same task source, at different times of the page's life. And event listeners don't all fire in an task queue, for instance `scroll` events are not part of a task queue but ran as part of the "update the rendering" steps in the event loop processing model.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah, right, the spec distinguishes further between queues and sources, but the difference is not really observable. Edited anyway.